# Python polynomial pow

Tags: math, python-3.6

I have my own defined **Polynomial class**, which is in form of list of coefficients.
Something like

> axˆ2 + bx + c is equals to [c, b, a]
>       (for ax + b == [b, a]
>       similarly, for axˆ3 + bxˆ2 + cx + d == [d, c, b, a])

and the **len()** of list depends of the index of function.
I want to define a custom __pow__ function but I really have no idea how to implement it.

Comment: Maybe you should define a multiplication function?

Comment: Why not simply use `**` or even a custom multiply function.

Comment: I can't use standard ** because I have to do something like (x + 1)(x + 1) = (xˆ2 + 2x + 1), so [1, 1] ** 2 would be [1, 2, 1]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a function to get the coefficients of two polynomials when you multiply them together.

```
def multiply(a, b):
    """
        polynomials where.
        [a1, a2, a3] -> a1 + a2*x + a3*x^2
        [b1, b2, b3] -> b1 + b2*x + b3*x^2
    """
    c = [0.0]*(len(a) + len(b)-1)

    for i in range(len(a)):
        ai = a[i]
        for j in range(len(b)):
            c[i + j] += ai * b[j]

    return c


x = [1, 1]
y = [2, 1, 0]
print(multiply(x, y))
```

Which shows `[2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 0]`.

Then make a pow function to call multiply in a loop.

```
def pow(a, n):
    """
     a^n
    """
    c = [1]
    for i in range(n):
        c = multiply(c, a)
    return c

x = [1, 1]
print(pow(x, 4))
```

Which outputs `[1.0, 4.0, 6.0, 4.0, 1.0]` as expected.

Comment: In your first snippet, why do you use an example of `y` with a leading coefficient of zero? That is not completely invalid but it is unusual and makes the example more complicated than needed.

Comment: No reason, I just typed out three random numbers. It should probably be done more systematically. And yes in retrospect, it is a pretty bad example to use.

Comment: This approach is fundamentally sound, but for powers higher than two or three you will do much better to use [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) than to multiply n times.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, there are multiple answers here, depending on what you mean by defining the "**pow**" function.

So, first of all, as @matt has already correctly stated, a power is just repeated multiplication. Python actually has a pow function inbuilt, but there's also the quick notation using `a**2 = a squared = a*a` or `a**3 = a * a * a` or `a**4=a * a * a * a` etc.

Now, if you just want the pow of each x argument, your function would look something like this

```
a*(x**2)+b*x+c
```

or

```
a*(x**4)+b*(x**3)+c*(x**2)+d*x+e
```

Finally, you'd probably want your coefficients to be listed, so you could do something like this

```
coefficients = [1,2,3,...] #(inputting real values here)
def poly(x):
     sum=0.0
     for i in range(len(coefficients)):
          sum+=coefficients[i]*(x**i)
     return sum
```

That could then return you the polynomial defined by the coefficient list "coefficients" and return to you the value at any point "x".

I hope it helped :)

edit:: Just read your comment, gonna append that to my answer in a second.

Was a bit too fast typing my second edit, just use the alogrithm provided by the other answer :)

edit2::

As matt pointed out ::

```
 def __mult__(coeff1,coeff2):
     coeff_result = [0.0]*(len(coeff1)+len(coeff2)-1)
     for k in range(len(coeff1)):
         for n in range(len(coeff2)):
              coeff_result[k+n]+=coeff1[k]*coeff2[n]
     return coeff_result
 def __pow__(coeff1,n):
     res = coeff1[:]
     for i in range(n-1):
         res=__mult__(res,coeff1)
     return res
```

does the trick for integer exponents (non-integer exponents wouldn't return 
 valid polynomials).

Comment: Did you try your code? What is n? Isn't max going to be bigger than either length array so k is going to be larger than either length array?